# signed apk error [WifiManagerLeak]

Tags: android

I can create debug apk. But when I try to generate a signed apk, I receive the following message:

> Error: The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application
>   context or memory will leak on devices < Android N. Try changing  to
>   .getApplicationContext()  [WifiManagerLeak]

Comment: Why do you think you are receiving the error? At what exact moment does the error occur?

Comment: Can you try doing what it suggests you do?

Answer (score 38):

As the error suggests, it seems that `WiFiManager` must use the `ApplicationContext`, as opposed to the `ActivityContext`, otherwise a memory leak can occur. The error was triggered by following code:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

To fix the issue I replaced the above line with:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I used the suggested fix - changed  "activity.getSystemService" to  "activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService" and now facing the problem in connecting to WI-FI. can somebody explain me if this fix can cause issues with WI-FI? thanks

Comment: in case you are in a library not an activity use
context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)

Comment: do I need to import any class or create any object? Cause I am getting error when I used getApplicationContext() or context.getApplicationContext() . for second one(context.getApp...) i tried to create context object of Context class but I think this require more info to create the object.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added following code in build.gradel - module.app and now successfully build the app

( suggested by android studio itself )

lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }